# Robolectric returns 0 height for a view with wrap content height

Tags: android, layout, view, robolectric, layout-inflater

I have an android customView which I want to test.

Few of the tests simulate a scroll of N dps when N is a subView height.

I run the tests with robolectric, but I always get in runtime that `subView.getHeight() == 0`

That's becuause the subView's height is defined as `wrap_content` and I guess robolectric doesn't inflate all the views to get this accurate info.

For example the `subView.getWidth > 0` as its defined as `match parent`.

Here is my test `@before` method:

```
@Before
  public void setUp() {

    myView.getHeaderView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
          @Override
          public void onGlobalLayout() {
            myHeight =
                myView.getHeaderView().getHeight();
          }
        });

    activityScenarioRule
        .getScenario()
        .onActivity(activity -> activity.setContentView(myView));
    activityScenarioRule.getScenario().moveToState(State.RESUMED);
  }
```

How can I still get the wrap content height at test runtime?

The code does call `onGlobalLayout` but returns `height==0`

Comment: Try to call measure() and layout() on your SubView, &/or set a ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener on the SubView and from there you get the View Dimensions

Comment: doesn't it called automatically? you mean to call from prod code?

Comment: You may get the height too fast for the subview, a reason for why it return 0, if on the prod code you are getting the View dimensions before the View is ready, it's better to get it with a ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener so you are sure the view has called it's methods, you can test it on the Test code for the moment and see if it's work

Comment: but why do i get the view's height then?

Comment: registering to `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` in the test `@before` didn't solve it

Comment: @Benda you get the first View height by "luck" and too fast to get the second, getting the height synchronously when the View are about to be drawn may result in dimensions returning 0(getHeight() before the view is ready), with the ViewTreeObserver you are sure you can get the View infos, if it did not worked then your problem may lie elsewhere too, try as stated in my first comment to call measure() and layout() see if it's work

Answer (score 2):

Use
@TextLayoutMode(REALISTIC) annotation above your test method.